# How to simulate a cable-driven soft robot in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, soft-robotics

[image]

A cable-driven soft arm, as shown in the diagram below, was modeled using PCC. The arm was divided into several segments, and the forward kinematics for each segment, as well as the overall kinematics equation, were derived based on the bending deformation relationship of the flexible arm.

Now, I want to simulate it in Gazebo. Currently, I have a rough understanding that each segment established in the forward kinematics can be treated as a link in Gazebo, and the pose equations for each link can be obtained. Finally, I need to write a Gazebo control plugin to implement the simulation. However, I am not sure about the specific steps to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to create an SDFormat file that contains all the links and joints. Make sure to use proper mass and moment of inertia parameters (if you use Gazebo Harmonic, there's a way to automatically compute this). You can then run gazebo without any controllers to make sure the passive behavior is as you expect. Once you are happy with that, you can use one of the joint controllers in Gazebo. Since you'll have many joints, I'd recommend [`JointTrajectoryController`](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1JointTrajectoryController.html) (see [example](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/joint_trajectory_controller.sdf))